# ¿Como saber cuando imprimen una hoja en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Hoy me enfrento a un contador de impresiones.

Tengo un micro sitio web que da constancias. Necesito tener un contador que cuente cuantas veces se han impreso las constancias, todo bien hasta ahí.

Mi problema es que no puedo usar la función `window.print()` uso una función de `jsPDF. autoPrint()`

Cuando sale la hoja de impresión quisiera detectar cuando le dan **clic** al botón de imprimir.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo la menor idea de como escuchar el evento de esta ventana.

Answer (score 5):

Hay una forma usando `window.matchMedia`, cuando abres el diálogo o haces una acción, imprime el objeto `MediaQueryListEvent`, supongo que cada navegador experimenta distíntos cambios en ese objeto. En cuanto al click en "Imprimir" habría que ver que pasa en dicho objeto en cada navegador. Ejemplo:

```
window.matchMedia('print').addListener((evento)=>{console.log(evento);});
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías suscribir un evento a [`afterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint)

> La propiedad `onafterprint` de `WindowEventHandlers` mixin es un `EventHandler` para procesar eventos `afterprint` para la ventana actual. Estos eventos se generan **después de que el usuario imprime, o si cancelan el diálogo de impresión**.

#### Ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener("afterprint", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
```